# Jaxrs web app cannot log to external file with Apache commons + utils.logging

Tags: java, maven, logging, jax-rs, apache-commons

I have a simple Jaxrs service where I want to write logs to external file. Though the logs are printed in the server console, they are not printing to external log file I specified. Following is the configurartions I followed.

in src/main/resources I have two files called commons-logging.properties and log-config.properties which I have configurations in the pom.xml to copy them to target/classes.

commons-logging.properties following configuration.

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
```

and log-config.properties contains following.

```
    # The following creates two handlers
    handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
    # Set the default logging level for the root logger
    .level=SEVERE
    # log level for the "com.example" package
    sample.logging.level=FINE
    # Set the default logging level
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=FINE
    # Set the default formatter
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
    # Specify the location and name of the log file
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern={path to my log file}
```

Jaxrs service class has following.

```
package org.test.testproject;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Path("/")
public class TestService {
    //private static final Logger customLog = Logger.getLogger(TestService.class.getName());
    private static final Log wso2Log = LogFactory.getLog(TestService.class);
    private static Logger customLog = Logger.getLogger(TestService.class.getName());

    @GET
    @Path("/customers/{id}/")
    public void getCustomer(@PathParam("id") String id) {

        customLog.info("get customer information Custom logging for " + id);

        wso2Log.info("----invoking getCustomer, Customer id is: " + id);
    }
}
```

Its compiling and I can retrieve the .war file. After deploying it only shows the logs in the server console. Am I missing anything here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the project dependencies and ensure that you don't have both `commons-logging` and `jcl-over-slf4j` in `WEB-INF/lib` or otherwise on the classpath.  If you have both, exclude one of them.  I've seen apps with both that fail to log messages to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked but it seems i do not have such duplicate files.